# How can i change TabItem Visibility programmatically?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I want to change the visibility of tab items in tablayout according to a value in code. How can I do that?

Comment: can you provide what have you done so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 
`tabLayout.removeTabAt(int position)` to remove a tab at a particular position. Then use `tabLayout.addTab(Tab tab, int position)` to add it again.